# java pdf file write

Tags: java

I am working with Java and I was wondering how to do a page break in a PDF file? After 50 lines I want to start writing on a new page.

I am using the iText library.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the iText library for creating a PDF in Java

```
Document document = new Document();
try {
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));
document.open();
document.add(
new Paragraph("Hello World"));
document.newpage(); 

// You are on the new page from here.
// Note that newpage method won't work on empty pages, 
// so first you should add something to previous page and then call this method 
// to create new page

} catch (Exception e) {
// handle exception
}
document.close();
```